# Prevent address bar from doing web searches and autocompletes

Tags: macos, firefox

How do I turn off the Firefox (v 33) search the web from the address bar feature?  I followed the instructions in Firefox help by changing the keyword `enabled` value to `false`, but the address bar continues to give me search results rather than the page I try to access.  I want to go to the URL I type in, not get a list of search results with links to it.  My system is Mac Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

**To Turn off  web search,**

In the Location bar, type about:config and press Enter.

[image]

The about:config "This might void your warranty!" warning page may appear. Click I'll be careful, I promise! to continue to the about:config page.

[image]

In the Search field, type keyword.enabled.

Double-click the keyword.enabled preference to set its value to false.

[image]

**To Disable URL autocomplete,**

In the Search field, type fixup.

Double-click the browser.fixup.alternate.enabled preference to set its value to false.

[image]

Source:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-web-address-bar#w_domain-guessing

Comment: You should include the instructions present in the link in case the link goes down.